Man is put on trial with robot judge and turns into a robot
I don't remember this movie's name, and I have looked all around. I have looked for this movie everywhere. I can't find it, I think it played on the sci-fi channel, sometimes between 2000-2008.
It is about a guy who escapes from an underground city (not much of a city, mostly beds, where the poor people live) to the surface. I remember that the people from the underground are allowed some time on the surface every year, one hour I believe.
Anyway, the character breaks out during this time, and he knows he is probably going to die, I think he cuts himself on some barbed wire, and he takes a tracker out of him. Eventually he travels on the surface, I remember that it isn't anything pretty, and then he finds some officers who are harassing a woman.
I don't remember much after, expect that he is put on trial and has a robot judge and lawyer, and in the end something gets put into his neck and he turns into a robot. It is cheesy, and although this will sound dumb, I think the movie had something to do with Steven Hawking's fear of AI. 

Sounds similar to the Syfy channel movie Android Apocalypse (2006): The surface of the planet is uninhabitable, main character is from a poor underground city, escapes from underground city and travels on the surface, later arrested and convicted by androids. Although if memory serves correct, I don't think he is turned into a robot at the end.



